# TypeScript Intellisense On Object Value Strings

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface, webstorm

I have a TypeScript `.d.ts` file that I am trying to define a function that takes in an options object. Based on one of the properties of the options object I would like to have intellisense on object values from the object returned from the first function. Here is an example:

carTypings.d.ts

```
interface LoadOptions {
    /** Type of Car */
    type: Type;
}

interface LoadOptions_Tesla {
    /** Type of Car */
    type: Type.TESLA;
}

interface LoadOptions_Chevy {
    /** Type of Car */
    type: Type.CHEVY;
}

interface GetStyleOptions {
    /** Model of car. */
    model: string;
}

interface GetStyleOptions_Tesla {
    /** Model of car. */
    model: 'Model S' | 'Model 3' | 'Model X';
}

interface GetStyleOptions_Chevy {
    /** Model of car. */
    model: 'Volt' | 'Bolt' | 'Malibu';
}

type Style = 'Sedan' | 'SUV' | 'Truck';

interface GenericCar {
    /** Returns the style of a car. */
    getStyle(options: GetStyleOptions): Style;
    /** The record type. */
    type: Type | string;
}

interface Tesla extends GenericCar {
    /** Returns the style of a car. */
    getStyle(options: GetStyleOptions_Tesla): Style;
}

interface Chevy extends GenericCar {
    /** Returns the style of a car. */
    getStyle(options: GetStyleOptions_Chevy): Style;
}

interface CarLoadFunction {
    (options: LoadOptions_Tesla): Tesla;
    (options: LoadOptions_Chevy): Chevy;
    (options: LoadOptions): GenericCar;
}

export const enum Type {
    TESLA = 1,
    CHEVY = 2,
    ITIALIAN = 3
}

export let load: CarLoadFunction;
```

cars.ts

```
import * as record from './carTypings'

let someItalianCar = record.load({ type: record.Type.ITIALIAN });
someItalianCar.getStyle({ model: 'Italian Model Z' }); //<— I don’t get an error here but intellisense is recommending me the Tesla models, which it should not.

let teslaRec = record.load({ type: record.Type.TESLA });
teslaRec.getStyle({ model: 'Model 3' }); //<— This works as expected

let chevyRec = record.load({ type: record.Type.CHEVY });
chevyRec.getStyle({ model: 'Bolt' }); //<—This also does not give me an error but intellisense recommended the Tesla models instead of the Chevy ones.
```

In the `cars.ts` file I would like it so that if I load a car record of type `CHEVY`, when I call `.getStyle` the only options for model are 'Volt,’ 'Bolt' or 'Malibu.’ Likewise if I load a car that doesn’t have a specific definition (like the ‘someItalianCar’) I shouldn’t get any intellisense. Currently I get the Tesla models as intellisense in all cases no matter what the type. I believe this is caused by the `CarLoadFunction` definition because the Tesla option is the first one to be defined but I don’t know any other way of writing it.

I should also note that I'm using IntelliJ's WebStorm as my IDE. I do not know if TypeScript behavior is different in other IDE's.

Comment: do you have a tsconfig.json file in the project?